# arrays returning empty when logging them outside of their loop?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
const rp      = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const request = require('request')


homeTeam = [];  //home team
awayTeam = [];  //away team
openOdds = [];  //opening odds
currOdds = [];  //current odds
awayPerc = [];  //away money distribution
homePerc = [];  //home money distribution

//sports action API connection
const options = {
  url: 'https://api-prod.sprtactn.co/web/v1/scoreboard/mlb?date=20180520',
  json: true
}

//sports action money distribution scrape and push to array
request('https://www.actionnetwork.com/mlb/live-odds', function (err, res, html) {
  if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);

    $('td.text-right.border-left span:first-child').each(function(i, element) {
      const awayPercs = $(this).text(); 
      const homePercs = $(this).next().text(); 
      awayPerc.push({awayPercs})
      homePerc.push({homePercs})
    });

  }});



//home team, away team, opening odds, and closing odds API pull
rp(options)
  .then((data) => { 

  const games = data.games

  games.forEach((games) => {

    games.teams.forEach((teams, i) => {
      if (games.home_team_id == games.teams[i].id) {
        homeTeam.push({homeTeam: games.teams[i].full_name}); 
      } else if (games.away_team_id == games.teams[i].id) {
        awayTeam.push({awayTeam: games.teams[i].full_name}); 
      }
    })

    games.odds.forEach((odds, i) => {
      if (games.odds[i].type == "game" && games.odds[i].book_id == "15") {
        currOdds.push({curAway: games.odds[i].ml_away, curHome: games.odds[i].ml_home})
      } else if (games.odds[i].type == "game" && games.odds[i].book_id == "30") {
        openOdds.push({openAway: games.odds[i].ml_away , openHome: games.odds[i].ml_home})
      }
    })

  })
})
  .catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
})

console.log(awayPerc)
```

Whenever I try to log any of my arrays outside of their respective loops it returns an empty array. If I declare the array outside the function shouldn't I be able to access it's results anywhere? If I log the array within it's respective loop it works fine, but outside it's empty.

Comment: Don't mix `request` with `request-promise`. Just always use promises (which will also allow you easily to wait for the array to be filled before logging them)

Answer (score 0):

Make your array Public and it should work.

Comment: What do you mean by public?